# DB Constraint Violation in - possibly domain_id

Tags: webform-civicrm, extension, contributions, paypal, civicrm-entity

I have been presented with the following error on when using civicrm-webform and paypal standard:

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: DB Constraint Violation - possibly domain_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for this API. If so, please raise a bug report. in civicrm_api3() (line 45 of /home/shishukunj/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php).

Is this a site specific issue or something to do with the core or the module?

Happy to help fix in either case as we are now committed to using 4.7 but need to iron out the bugs as we using webform-civicrm, related permissions and paypal payments heavily.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue using the OmniPay extension for CiviCRM with Payment Express.  I get an error when trying to click through to the offsite payment processor. If I remove the credit card processor from the underlying contribution page and just allow Pay Later, I have no problem completing the registration.

Comment: exactly the same error, using 4.7, webform, paypal standard. except for the path to your sites homedirectory :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT AN ANSWER but I am not allowed to comment since I only have 49 points. Seems ridiculous to me since I have been working with CiviCRM for over 8 years. Anyway I have the same problem as described above except that I am using eWay Payment processor.
Is anyone able to respond with advice on this issue?

Comment: We also have a similar situation using CiviCRM 4.7 with Webforms and Paypal Standard.